# Solve system of logical equations

Tags: co.combinatorics, lo.logic

I need a general method for solving systems of logical equations like:
$$
\begin{equation*}
 \begin{cases}
  c_{0} = a_{0} \land b_{0}\\\\ 
  c_{1} = a_{0} \land b_{1} ⊕ a_{1} \land b_{0}\\\\ 
  c_{2} = a_{0} \land b_{2} ⊕ a_{1} \land b_{1} ⊕ a_{2} \land b_{0}\\\\ 
  c_{3} = a_{1} \land b_{2} ⊕ a_{2} \land b_{1}\\\\ 
  c_{4} = a_{2} \land b_{2} 
 \end{cases}
\end{equation*}
$$
Where c is known and a and b are unknown variables.
This system is a system of logical nonlinear equations, I want to know if it is possible to find a general solution for such a system. The number of unknowns is 1 more than the number of equations. Solutions will be symmetric (a and b can be swapped).
The challenge is not unsolvable and there is an example of a [solution](https://macton.github.io/codingame/nintendo/00000001.html) . However, it seems to me that there is a simpler solution.

Comment: Doesn't quite fit with XOR-SAT https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Boolean_satisfiability_problem#XOR-satisfiability so I don't know.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Let $A=a_0+a_1x+a_2x^2\cdots+a_nx^n$, $B=b_0+b_1x+\cdots+b_mx^m$, and $C=AB=c_0+\cdots+c_{n+m}x^{n+m}$, where arithmetic occurs over $\mathbb{F}_2$.  Then your problem is exactly equivalent to recovering $\{A,B\}$ from $C$.  This is the problem of [factorization of polynomials over finite fields](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Factorization_of_polynomials_over_finite_fields).  Although, remarkably, the factors can be computed in polynomial time, I don't there there are any particularly simple algorithms for doing so.